# Cannot access attributes of node

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am in the function that is called for custom menu items.  Why doesn't node.attr('id') or $(node).attr('id') not work?

Tree init:

```
$("div#treeView").jstree({
    plugins: ["themes", "ui", "json_data", "crrm", "contextmenu"],
    themes: { "icons": false },
    "json_data": jsondata, 
    contextmenu: { items: customMenu, select_node: true }
});
```

node.attr('type') returns undefined:

```
function customMenu(node) {
    // The default set of all items
    var items = {
        deleteItem: { // The "delete" menu item
            label: "Delete",
            action: function () { alert("delete"); }
        }
    };

    if (node.attr('type') == "report") delete items.deleteItem;

    return items;
}
```

Here is the structure when I add a node to the tree:

```
CreateTreeNode: function (id, title, type, metadata) {
    var newNode = {
        "data":
        {
            "title": title,
            "attr":
            {
                "id": id,
                "type": type
            }
        },
        "metadata": (metadata == undefined ? {} : metadata),
        "children": []
    };
    return newNode;
}
```

Comment: What does `console.log(node)` show you?

Comment: Are you sure node is a jQuery object? If not you probably first need to make it before you can use the attr function like: $(node).attr("id")

Comment: I get the following for node: {...}
    [prototype]: {...}
    [0]: {...}
    [prototype]: []
    context: {...}
    length: 1
    prevObject: {...}

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond, I had to carpool.

Comment: When I type in node.data() I get the following but this is the metadata from the structure : {...}
    [prototype]: {...}
    contractId: "112"
    contractTreeId: "Working112"
    inspDate: "12/3/2013"
    reportId: "112i20131203"
    tree: "Working"

Comment: I changed if (node.attr('type') == "report") delete items.deleteItem; to if (!node.data().reportId) delete items.deleteItem; This works but I would prefer to access the type attribute.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.